# How to create html table week view ? (Calendar)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, calendar, html-table

I would like to create a html table with week view (calendar) like this:

[image]

How can I create a table like that ?

Also I would like to do database operations.

Is there any plug-in for that because I have searched everywhere but I did not find. I'll use Asp.Net and  MSSQL.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to decide which server side language to use (like php).

Then you can find a lot of examples for this by googling "calendar table in php" etc.

To do database operations you first have to set up a database.  MySQL or similar.

If you already have done this, post what you use and I will try to help.

Comment: Thanks. I'll use Asp.Net and MSSQL.

Comment: If you want advice on this: Asp.Net MVC is a lot better than classic Asp.Net to work with (opinion).

Comment: Thank you, I am learning MVC structure. How can I create above table with DB operations ?

Comment: Start out by writing the code for creating the html table, no DB needed for that.

Comment: I can create table like that but I cannot combine with calendar. For example; when clicked right button of this week the table changing.